# Django How do I show Author (user) name instea of ID?

Tags: python, django

I have a custom user model (CustomUsers) on one app called users, and then I have a model called Bookings from which I have created a ModelfForm called BookingsForm.

In the Bookings model (and ultimately the BookingsForm), I have a field called booking_author which has a ForeignKey inherited from the CustomUsers model.

Now I have been able to successfully call the booking_author field into my bookingscreate view and make it uneditable/read only as I had wanted. The issue now is that the field is displaying the id of the author instead of the name of the author. Is anyone able to help me resolve this?

## views.py

```
@login_required
def bookingscreate(request):
    bookings_form = BookingsForm(initial={'booking_author': request.user })
    context = {
        'bookings_form': bookings_form
    }
    return render(request, 'bookings_create.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of getting the users name. To obtain the user name in this case you could use

```
request.user.get_full_name()
request.user.get_short_name()
```

**Explanation:**

request.user is the User object, and thus you have access to all user methods. If the above is not what you're looking for you could create a method in your user class and then call that method in this view.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I followed your logic and it worked.  

```bookings_form = BookingsForm(initial={'booking_author': request.user.email })``` 

This also worked when I did the following: 

```bookings_form = BookingsForm(initial={'booking_author': request.user.first_name+request.user.last_name})```

Comment: Thats great, I'm glad its working for you!
Just a tip, in order for this code to be more DRY, you could use the user method to join the user name like you've done above.

Comment: Agreed, adding it to my list of to-do's as we speak. Thanks again :)